# webpack-cli TypeError: compiler.plugin is not a function

Tags: npm, webpack, prestashop-1.7

I'm totally new to prestashop development and all of that stuff and if u reply pls use simplest explanation possible. I'm actually new to web tech too. There is a problem with webpack when im trying to use 'npm run watch' and it says

> [webpack-cli] TypeError: compiler.plugin is not a function
> at ExtractTextPlugin.apply (C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\themes\classic_dev\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\index.js:233:11)
> at createCompiler (C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\themes\classic_dev\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:69:12)
> at create (C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\themes\classic_dev\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:113:15)
> at webpack (C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\themes\classic_dev\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:121:46)
> at f (C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\themes\classic_dev\node_modules\webpack\lib\index.js:37:15)
> at WebpackCLI.createCompiler (C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\themes\classic_dev\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1337:24)
> at async WebpackCLI.bundleCommand (C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\themes\classic_dev\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1433:20)
> at async Command. (C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\themes\classic_dev\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:384:25)
> at async Promise.all (index 1)
> at async Command. (C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\themes\classic_dev\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:824:13)
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 2
> npm ERR! prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0 watch: `webpack --progress --watch`
> npm ERR! Exit status 2
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0 watch script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

the complete log is

```
> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'watch'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.10
3 info using node@v14.15.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewatch', 'watch', 'postwatch' ]
5 info lifecycle prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0~prewatch: prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0~watch: prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0~watch: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0~watch: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\themes\classic\_dev\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\ja\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\ja\bin;C:\Python39\Scripts;C:\Python39;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin;C:\Users\ja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts;C:\Users\ja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38;C:\Users\ja\geckodriver.exe;C:\Users\ja\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ja\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin;C:\Users\ja\.pyenv\pyenv-win\bin;C:\Users\ja\.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims;C:\xampp\php;C:\Users\ja\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
9 verbose lifecycle prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0~watch: CWD: C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\themes\classic\_dev
10 silly lifecycle prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0~watch: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'webpack --progress --watch' ]
11 silly lifecycle prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0~watch: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0~watch: Failed to exec watch script
13 verbose stack Error: prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0 watch: `webpack --progress --watch`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\themes\classic\_dev
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "watch"
18 verbose node v14.15.4
19 verbose npm  v6.14.10
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0 watch: `webpack --progress --watch`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the prestashop-classic-dev-tools@1.0.0 watch script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

I already tried to reinstall Node and webpack and also tried to run this with my antivirus off but nothing seems to work